# cant see android app after ./gradlew installDebug on device

Tags: android, pytorch

I have recently started learning to build android apps, and I am trying to follow the instructions from the [Pytorch website](https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/), which says:

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app.git
cd HelloWorldApp
./gradlew installDebug
```

I have my device plugged in and I ran the above and got:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
```

But.. I cannot find the application on the phone..
I am baffled as to why this is.

I would REALLY appreciate any directions to troubleshoot this - spent the last two hours on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is being installed normally, but not automatically opened after installation. You just need to find it amongst other apps on your device/emulator. [image]